# How do I use timeit module inside a decorator

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm creating a decorator to primarily `timeit` any function it decorates. And I'm unable to get it right. Throws `max recursion depth error`. Could someone please help me understand why it is happening and how to achieve this timeit implementation. **I don't want to use `time` module**

```
import timeit
from functools import wraps


def tool(func):
    """Include debug statement and timeit setup"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        print func.__doc__, args,
        res = func(*args)
        print res
        CODE = "func{args}".format(args=args)
        times = timeit.repeat(
            stmt=CODE,
            setup="from __main__ import {func} as func".format(func=func.__name__),
            repeat=3, number=10000)
        print times
    return wrapper
```

Comment: probably because the import thing get you the already decorated function, you have to use the not string version of the call to timeit

Comment: You have timeit inside your decorated function, so when you call it, it calls timeit, and the timeit is calling your function, which has timeit in it and so on and so forth. So there is a recursion here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem as I mention is in the setup, doing that import get you the already decorated function, that when executed once again do the import and get the decorated function and goes and execute the import and soo on until it blow up the stack... and we don't want that.

The [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) module can also take function as its stmt, so with just building a lambda  function it solve the problem and we can use the undercoated function that way

> The stmt and setup parameters can also take objects that are callable without arguments. This will embed calls to them in a timer function that will then be executed by timeit(). Note that the timing overhead is a little larger in this case because of the extra function calls.

```
import timeit
from functools import wraps
    
def tool(func):
    """Include debug statement and timeit setup"""
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        print(func.__doc__, args)
        res = func(*args)
        print(res)
        times = timeit.repeat(
            stmt=lambda: func(*args),
            repeat=3, number=10000)
        print(times)
    return wrapper
```

and a quick test

```
>>> @tool
def fun():
    return 42
>>> fun()
None ()
42
[0.0013318000000026586, 0.0013294000000314554, 0.0013452000000597764]
>>>
```